# How to determine "LCM" like value of a data series?

Tags: python, modeling

I am analyzing data for [Millikan - Fletcher's Oil drop experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment). In short, I have various values of charge Q, and would like to determine the "LCM" like value of this data series - which would correspond to the smallest quantization of charge.

I would like to know how this can be done algorithmically, preferably in Python. The data is somewhat noisy. For reference, you can check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/96254/oil-drop-experiment-and-quantization-of-charge/96320) question on Physics Stackexchange (see the first answer). Something like that method will help. I have still not understood how that algorithms works exactly.

Comment: There, is an algorithm in Richard A. Becker, John M. Chambers and Allan R. Wilks. 1988. _The New S Language: A Programming Environment for Data Analysis and Graphics_ but my copy is not accessible to me at present.

Comment: @NickCox Do you happen to remember any more details? I have the book, and can check

Comment: It is on p.273. I didn't find my book, still 1.5 km away, but I remembered posting about it. https://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2011-11/msg00730.html

Answer (score 9):

How you determine an appropriate "LCM" will depend on how you [model the data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/generative-models/info). In the example you link, the model is something like
$$
q_i = \left(k_i + \epsilon_i\right)b
$$
where $q_i$ is a measurement, $k_i$ is a positive integer, the $\epsilon_i$ are [iid](/questions/tagged/iid) measurement errors, and $b$ is a fixed (positive) base unit that does not vary between samples $i$.

The approach taken in your linked example is to estimate $b$ (and the $k$ values) by minimizing an estimate of the error magnitude. To see how this works, consider the following.

Given a value for $b$, the model equation can be rearranged to
$$
\frac{q_i}{b} = k_i + \epsilon_i
$$
where $k_i$ is a positive integer, and $\epsilon_i$ is expected to be "small". So a reasonable estimate for $k_i$ would be
$$
\hat{k}_i = \max\left[\mathrm{round}\left[\frac{q_i}{b}\right], 1\right]
$$
which gives an error estimate
$$
\hat{\epsilon}_i = \frac{q_i}{b} - \hat{k}_i
$$

The total error* could then be estimated as
$$
E(b) = \sum_i \vert\hat{\epsilon}_i\vert
$$
and then the final "LCM" estimate is gotten by minimizing the estimated total error
$$
\hat{b} = \arg\min_{b>0}E(b)
$$
where only positive values of $b$ are considered.
In python, this could be done with [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize_scalar-bounded.html) (using e.g. $b\leq2q_\min$ as an upper bound).

(*Note: For [Laplace](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/laplace-distribution/info) errors, this would be the negative log-likelihood, and $\hat{b}$ would be the [mle](/questions/tagged/mle).)

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Seems to be an interesting method.

Comment: One question, why are you using $2q_{min}$ as the upper bound? I can't understand the logic behind that.

Comment: Also, in my actual data, I seem to be getting a monotonically decreasing function, impyling $2q_{min}$ is the best estimate for $b$. Hence, the last question.

Comment: The upper bound comment was just an example, not meant to be general. Sorry for the miscommunication. Also, this answer was mainly just translating your linked Physics.SE approach into more "stats" language. (To ensure appropriate for this site. Else could be closed as a "coding" question.)

Comment: Now I remember why I chose that upper bound:  if $b > 2q_\min$ then $q_\min/b < 1/2$, so rounds to $0$.